# How prove this systems-equation has least two postive integers solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

> Show that：
>   for any $k\ge 100,(k\in N^{+})$, there exsit $p\in N^{+}$, such
>   $$\begin{cases}
> a+b+c=k\\
> abc=p\\
> a>b>c
> \end{cases}$$
>   has at least two postive integers solution $(a,b,c)$

This links some people say use mathematical induction,But I think can't solve it.so I use Vieta's formulas consider
$$x^3-kx^2+() x-p=0$$ What approaches do you think I could take to solving the next step？

This problem is from when I solve this following  [Mathmematician 2014](http://cache.data.data.data.gmailtest.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h592842p3515110):

Comment: This is an old question from the Mediterranean Mathematical Olympiad 2011. Solutions are given right at the page you have linked.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, are there solutions beyond the brief posts saying "use induction" without details?

Comment: @vadim123 Usually the contests have online-solutions; certainly the users of "art of problem solving" will send you one.

Comment: @DietrichBurde,I can't find this problem is 2011 ？can you links?

Comment: [Here](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h420337) is the link, problem 3 at the end.

Comment: Hello,you are say this:http://cache.data.data.data.gmailtest.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h430444p2434100? I think this different problems

Comment: The induction was proposed by prople in artofproblemsolving is not working because they didnot understand the problem, they are thinking about only one solution

Comment: Try something like taking $c$ to the R.H.S of both the equations, then make quadratic equation with $a$ and $b$ as its roots? This is the approach I am trying but cannot proceed any further.

Comment: @Elaqqad,I agree with you,so I post this question.because I think  can't only use induction.maybe other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint/Short answer :** Look for pairs of triples of the form $(x,2y,3z),(6x,y,z)$.

**Longer answer:** I can show that the result already holds for $n\geq 83$ (also, a computer search shows that the largest $n$ for which there is no solution is $n=22$). Indeed, for
such $n$ let us put $u=\frac{n+1}{22}$ and $v=\frac{n-1}{17}$. We have 
$$v-u=\frac{5n-39}{374} \geq \frac{376}{374} > 1,$$ so that
there is a (necessarily positive) integer $a$ between $u$ and $v$.
Then $\frac{n}{22} < a <\frac{n}{17}$, and we may consider the triples
$p=(2a,4(n-17a),3(22a-n))$ and $p'=(2(n-17a),22a-n,12a)$.

All the entries in $p$ are distinct, except when $n$ is divisible by $35,64$ or $134$.

All the entries in $p'$ are distinct, except when $n$ is divisible by $23$ or $56$.

The triplets $p$ and $p'$ are distinct, except when $n=18a$  or
$n=20a$ (indeed, if we put $\sigma_2(x,y,z)=xy+xz+yz$, we have 
the identity $\sigma_2(p)-\sigma_2(p')=-10(n-18a)(n-20a)$).

So, if $n$ is divisible by none of $18,20,23,34,35,56,64$ or $134$, the triplets
$p$ and $p'$ satisfy all that we want and we are done.

The remaining  cases can be done by hand :

If $n$ is divisible by $20$, $n=20t$, consider triplets $q=t(1,9,10)$ and $q'=t(2,3,15)$.

If $n$ is divisible by $23$, $n=23t$, consider triplets $q=t(4,9,10)$ and $q'=t(5,6,12)$.

If $n$ is divisible by $35$, $n=35t$, consider triplets $q=t(1,14,20)$ and $q'=t(2,5,28)$.

If $n$ is divisible by $56$, $n=56t$, consider triplets $q=t(1,23,32)$ and $q'=t(2,8,46)$.

If $n$ is divisible by $64$, $n=64t$, consider triplets $q=t(1,30,33)$ and $q'=t(3,6,55)$.

If $n$ is divisible by $134$, $n=134t$, consider triplets $q=t(1,45,88)$ and $q'=t(3,11,120)$.

The only case left now is the case when $n=18a$ (so that $p$ and $p'$ coincide).

If $a$ is divisible by $2$, $a=2s$, consider triplets $q=s(2,13,21)$ and $q'=s(3,7,26)$.

If $a$ is divisible by $3$, $a=3s$, consider triplets $q=s(1,18,35)$ and $q'=s(2,7,45)$.

If $a$ is divisible by $5$, $a=5s$, consider triplets $q=s(1,24,65)$ and $q'=s(2,10,78)$.

If $a$ is divisible by $7$, $a=7s$, consider triplets $q=s(1,29,96)$ and $q'=s(4,6,116)$.

Otherwise, we must have $a\geq 11$, so $n\geq 18\times 11$ and reasoning as above
we see that $v-u\geq 2$ so there are at least two integers between $u$ and $v$. We can then
replace $a$ (such that $18a=n$) with an $a'$ such that $n\neq 18a'$, which concludes the proof.